# Why is makedirs() creating an empty file instead of a folder?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a Django app and using Python to create an upload folder. For now, I am using static names to test. My function creates an empty file only, not a folder.

I have tried both `mkdir()` and `makedirs()` with the same result. I am testing on Windows 10.

This is in my model:

```
def uploadloc(self, irun):
    if not os.path.exists('device1'):
        os.makedirs('device1')
    return 'device1'
iimage = models.ImageField(null=True, default=None, upload_to=uploadloc)
```

I think this should be creating a folder but it is only creating an empty file. `irun` is currently not used.

Comment: did you delete file `device1` before test ? And check in which folder it runs code - `os.getcwd()` (Current Working Directory) -  because it can create this folder in different place then you expect.

Comment: I see it creating in the correct and expected folder. But it is an empty file named 'device1', not a folder.

Comment: `makedirs` can't create file - so file has to be created before you run `uploadloc` and `exists('device1')` gives information that there is already object (file or folder) with name `'device1'` and it can't create folder with name `'device1'`

Comment: I would better check `os.getcwd()` because maybe it runs `exists()` and `makdirs()` in different folder then you expect and it already created `'device1'` in different palce - and you may have to use full path in `exists()` and `makedirs()` to create folder in correct place..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) for `ImageField` says that it inherits its arguments from `FileField`, where the semantics of the `upload_to` argument are [detailed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField):

> #### `FileField.upload_to`
>
> This attribute provides a way of setting the
>   upload directory and file name, and can be set in two ways. In both
>   cases, the value is passed to the `Storage.save()` method.
>
> If you specify a string value, it may contain `strftime()` formatting,
>   which will be replaced by the date/time of the file upload (so that
>   uploaded files don’t fill up the given directory). For example:
>
> ```py
> class MyModel(models.Model):
>     # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads
>     upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
>     # or...
>     # file will be saved to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads/2015/01/30
>     upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
> ```
>
> If you are using the default `FileSystemStorage`, the string value will be
>   appended to your `MEDIA_ROOT` path to form the location on the local
>   filesystem where uploaded files will be stored. If you are using a
>   different storage, check that storage’s documentation to see how it
>   handles `upload_to`.
>
> `upload_to` may also be a callable, such as a function. This will be
>   called to obtain the upload path, including the filename. This
>   callable must accept two arguments and return a Unix-style path (with
>   forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system.

Your callable takes the wrong number of arguments (`self` doesn't count), and since its return value is meant to include the filename, well... it does. When it returns `'default1'` to `ImageField()`, *that's* what's creating the empty file, using the name provided to it by the `upload_to` callable.

The `os.makedirs()`, if it's even succeeding, is creating that directory somewhere else entirely.

Comment: I understand that. But I can't even get that far because it does not create the folder.

Comment: My guess is it does, just somewhere else. (The script's current working directory, most likely. Which isn't `MEDIA_ROOT`.) And then when it returns 'default1', that's used as the filename in the `MEDIA_ROOT` output directory.

Comment: I see it creating in the correct and expected folder. But it is an empty file named 'device1', not a folder.

Comment: Here's a test you can do: Change the callable to `os.makedirs('foldername')`, but then `return 'othername'`. I suspect you'll find that it's the `ImageField()` call that's creating the empty file (based on the string returned to it), not your `os.makedirs()`.

Comment: I see my mistake! Thank you! Can I mark a comment as the correct answer?

Comment: @SinTekSolutions Glad you got it sorted out! I'll incorporate my followup comments into the answer, so it's all there.